Google Chrome v126 Print Page Layout Issue
I have an issue with the print page layout in the latest versions of Chrome and Edge (v126). When I adjust the scale settings in the print dialog, the page layout gets distorted and shifts to the left. I have attached a screenshot to illustrate the problem. Has anyone encountered this issue or know a solution?
in new version: ( The blurred part is the size of the element that I want to print ) 
Everything is correct in the old versions and in the Firefox browser
I think the page body is not hidden in print

There are definitely print issues in Chrome 126. I don't know if what you're describing is the same thing, but one issue I've been able to reproduce in a number of pages including my own is the contents get shifted vertically and off the page if you've scrolled down prior to printing. As a workaround, if you're a developer with any control of the print initiation in the your web app you can call window.scrollTo(0, 0) before calling any print commands. For extra good measure you can save off the scrolled coordinates before scrolling to 0,0 and then reset them after calling window.print().
https://support.google.com/chrome/thread/279981342/print-issue-when-printing-in-version-126-0-6478-62-64-bit?hl=en

I have exactly the same problem, the page goes to the right, and it was not fixed with this code either
window.scrollTo(0, 0)
What can be done to solve this problem faster?

I added the code below to solve this problem in every way anyone tries to print in Chrome.
window.addEventListener('beforeprint', function (event) { window.scrollTo(0, 0) });

No, the problem is not solved, the page is strangely pulled to the left

If you are using the "display: flex" for the container div, try to add "position: absolute" with it on printing (NOT "relative"). This fixed the problem on my case.
@media print {
 .your-class{
  display: flex !important;
  position: absolute !important;
 }
}

I believe this might help, as I encountered the same issue with Google Chrome version 126.

No, I don't use "display: flex" and I tested this code:
@media print {
.your-class{
position: absolute;
top: 0;
right: 0;
}
}
but it didn't work. The page moves to the left. It seems like there is an extra space when printing.

Fixed in 126.0.6478.127  version

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
